# Can ethylene glycol give victor mayer test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

I think there should be no problem for it to give red coloration in victor mayer test as a standard primary alcohol but a problem I encountered showed it otherwise.

Therefore, I would like to have a clear cut view of possibilities of what could happen, what actually happens and why?

Comment: Do you have a source for link about this test? Seems it's largely forgotten stuff from XIX century.

Comment: I am sorry as a friend of mine sent me this, this is the best i can give-
https://imgur.com/a/f596kXF

Comment: @Mithoron These are the references Wikipedia gives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Meyer#cite_note-2

Comment: @GaurangTandon I know, but these are ancient German texts. I more or less found out what's that supposed to be and it seems this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68546/reaction-of-ethylene-glycol-with-pi3p-i2 is related as halogenation using P is first step.