# Why is 1,2-diiodoethane unstable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halides

Diiodoethane is a product of the reaction between glycol and $\ce{PI3}$. Why is 1,2-diiodoethane unstable?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68546/reaction-of-ethylene-glycol-with-pi%e2%82%83-p-i%e2%82%82/111098#111098

Answer (score 4):

It isn't unstable at all.  1,2-diiodoethane is characterized with a melting point of 80–82 °C, and a mass spectrum with five major peaks.  It even serves as the iodine source in some rare earth iodide syntheses.  Read about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,2-Diiodoethane).

Comment: Although 1,2-diiodoethane is commercially available (_e.g._, Sigma-Aldrich), it has been recommended that it should be stored in $\pu{2-7 ^\circ C}$. Isn't that means it may tend to decompose?

Comment: [Please don't post links to the mobile versions of the websites (unless there is a really good reason to do so)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4358/41328).

Comment: Missed that, sorry.  Was having tea at the time.  Don't drink and derive ;-) .